# When prefix is missing for config properties, make the map to empty and not null

Tags: java, spring, dictionary, configuration, nullpointerexception

Currently, if my application.yml does not include the mapping of a property, my config class does not initializes the map and leaves it as null instead of empty. How can i make it be empty if no mapping is found?

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "someMapping")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@Getter
@Setter
public class HttpLoggingLevelProperties {
    private Map<String, String> loggingLevelMap;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just initialize the map yourself. In the default constructor or directly  on the field.

```
private Map<String, String> loggingLevelMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: Duh, makes sense. Wasn't sure if it would do the actual mapping when needed that way. Thanks

Comment: Now, is there a way to do this in a Java record without overriding the constructor?